# **kwargs in class defenition. Error : " __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, keyword-argument

```
class Test_class(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        for a in kwargs.values():
            print a

dic = {"a_list":1}

Test_class(dic)
```

Hello Everybody,
I am trying to understand what's wrong with the code. I am getting the following error:

> `__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Can anybody explain, please?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Instead of keyword arguments you have passed a single positional argument. The method does not accept any positional arguments beyond the implicit instance argument. Expand the dictionary when passing.

```
Test_class(**dic)
```

Comment: Thank you, mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your `__init__` to take a *named* argument, but you are passing in a *positional* argument. In order to properly instantiate the class based on your definition, you need to provide a proper named argument, *or* unpack your dictionary in your call:

```
Test_class(**dic)
```

If you want to pass an explicit named argument instead, you would then do something like:

```
Test_class(some_arg=dic)
```

However, based on what you are trying to do, I believe you are trying to do the first solution, where you want to pass your dictionary and use the "key" as the argument name.

Observe how your error is reproduced here, and then corrected:

```
>>> class Test_class(object):
...     def __init__(self,**kwargs):
...         for a in kwargs.values():
...             print(a)
...
>>> dic = {"a_list":1}
>>>
>>> Test_class(dic)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>> Test_class(a=dic)
{'a_list': 1}
<__main__.Test_class object at 0x10b505a10>
>>>
```

Using unpacking:

```
>>> Test_class(**{"a_list":1})
1
<__main__.Test_class object at 0x10b505a90>
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation, mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test_class(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print args
        for a in kwargs.values():
            print a

dic = {"a_list":1}

Test_class(dic)
```

as per your code it takes as args not as kwargs , for kwargs call

```
Test_class(**dic)
```

or call like that:

```
Test_class(a_list = 1)
```

Comment: Cheers :) Thanks a lot :)